# tkinter notebook widget frame limitation

Tags: python, tkinter, ttkwidgets

I was trying to set two different frame in one tab, but as I read somewhere on the internet
it is not possible with notebook widget.

I have problem with placing buttons - for example 8 buttons below 10 buttons.
the buttons below are smaller and having empty space between each button above on x axis....
I don't want to span them.. I want them in same size and stick them together in the middle. I used grid..

I wanted to use different frame to do that, then each line of buttons are separated from the other...
but it's not possible with the notebook widget, Am I right?
And I think using `.place( x=, y= )`it's annoying and take time...

Any suggestions please to simply do that ?

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk

window = tkinter.Tk()

nb = tkinter.ttk.Notebook(window)  
nb.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=10, rowspan=10)

frame = tkinter.Frame(nb)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

nb.add(frame, text = "Tab1")

button1 = tkinter.Button(frame, text="button1")
button2 = tkinter.Button(frame, text="button2")
button3 = tkinter.Button(frame, text="button3")

button4 = tkinter.Button(frame, text="button4")
button5 = tkinter.Button(frame, text="button5")
button6 = tkinter.Button(frame, text="button6")
button7 = tkinter.Button(frame, text="button7")
button8 = tkinter.Button(frame, text="button8")

button1.grid(row=0, column=0)
button2.grid(row=0, column=1)
button3.grid(row=0, column=2)
button4.grid(row=1, column=0)
button5.grid(row=1, column=1)
button6.grid(row=1, column=2)
button7.grid(row=1, column=3)
button8.grid(row=1, column=4)

window.mainloop()
```

In this example the buttons size are the same but in my code the buttons at rows=1 are different size because I'm attaching them to a png photo..

Comment: Please place your code here. It should be a minimal reproducible example so people can have a look at your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, I can't really attach my code..it's too long.. and i need to do adjustments so this is why I just explained it in a really simple way. but anyway I attached some example here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is possible to place multiple frames in Notebook. You'll have to make them a child object of the initial frame:

```
frame = tkinter.Frame(nb)
nb.add(frame, text = "Tab1")

frame1 = tkinter.Frame(frame)
frame1.pack(fill="both", expand="True")
frame2 = tkinter.Frame(frame)
frame2.pack(fill="both", expand="True")
```

Then you can place the buttons inside the child frames:

```
button1 = tkinter.Button(frame1, text="button1")
button2 = tkinter.Button(frame1, text="button2")
button3 = tkinter.Button(frame1, text="button3")

button4 = tkinter.Button(frame2, text="button4")
button5 = tkinter.Button(frame2, text="button5")
button6 = tkinter.Button(frame2, text="button6")
button7 = tkinter.Button(frame2, text="button7")
button8 = tkinter.Button(frame2, text="button8")
```

Finally you'll have to fiddle around to place the buttons within their own child frame as you want them to have:

```
button1.grid(row=0, column=0)
button2.grid(row=0, column=1)
button3.grid(row=0, column=2)
button4.grid(row=1, column=0)
button5.grid(row=1, column=1)
button6.grid(row=1, column=2)
button7.grid(row=1, column=3)
button8.grid(row=1, column=4)
```

This, for example, centers the buttons. Within the child frames, you could also try to use another geometry manager if it seems to fit your needs better.

Comment: You're welcome. That's why it is so important to place a piece of code to look at (which you did ;-)